# How to deserialize saved model in Weka-for-Android

Tags: android, weka, random-forest

I am facing a problem with loading saved model from sdcard.
In Weka's official wiki I found 2 ways to deserialize serialized models, but non of them works on Android.

```
//First Method
RandomForest rf = (RandomForest) weka.core.SerializationHelper.
    read(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/BC.model");

//Second Method
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/BC.model"));
RandomForest rf = new RandomForest();
rf = (RandomForest) ois.readObject();
```

I get this error in logcat:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: 
    weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest; Incompatible class (SUID): 
    weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest
```

Answer (score 1):

In android, you can only load a classifier model which is serialized by your android APP. Otherwise you will get the exception due to incompatible Serializable UID.

Answer (score 0):

```
        InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("example.model");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        cls = (Classifier) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
```

You may want to put your model in the assets folder. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Henry for you response :)
The problem is not whether I find the model file or not, the problem I think is in casting ios.readObect to RandomForest.
I tried putting it in assets but nothing changed.